# Defining Gurobi variables based on other variables

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am using **Python 3.9.12** and **Gurobi version 10.0.1** to solve a MILP and trying to define an absolute value of the difference between a gurobi variable and a given number. However, when defining the auxiliary variables ("deviation") as constraints, my model becomes infeasible.

These are the relevant code snippets:

```
# Define decision variables 
x = {}
y = {}
deviation = {}
```

```
# Adding variables to the Model

for j in range(m):
# Loop over days
    for i in range(n):
        # Adding variable to model as integer, with name and an upper bound
        x[i, j] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name=f"x[{i, j}]")
        # Adding a binary variable that indicates whether there is a collection on the current day or not
        y[i, j] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name=f"y[{i, j}]")

        # Adding the variables that is to be the difference between "x" and the mean
        deviation[i,j] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=f"deviation[{i,j}]")
```

Adding the constraints that should further define the variables:

```
for j in range(m):
    model.addConstrs((deviation[i,j] == x[i,j] - mean) for i in range(n))
```

So I tried to use the constraints to use the "deviation" variable at a later point in my objective function. I expected the "deviation" variable to simply take on the values of difference between "x" and the mean, but in fact Gurobi seems to not be able to solve my model anymore as soon as the constraints are added. So far, I have not used the variable "deviation" at a later point in my model (eg., in the objective function).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: It was because by default, the lower bound of each variable is zero and with the deviation becoming negative at times, this made the model infeasible.

This is the updated definition of the variable:

```
deviation[i,j] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=-GRB.INFINITY,  name=f"deviation[{i,j}]")
```